# lfd[ ]: SYSLOG check

Tags: lfd

Checking the messages log of my VPS, I get the following among other lines:

```
Aug 10 11:50:15 mail lfd[4894]: SYSLOG check [some capital and small letters here]
```

What does the alert say? Is it just saying that the lfd is functioning normally, or there is a problem?

Thanks

Comment: its writing a log line to ensure logging works, i presume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That log is from LFD which is part of config server firewall. It is possible to configure lfd to monitor system logs for systemwide issues.

If the log entry not saying that SYSLOG check failed. Then lfd is able to read and check system logs properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could not find this answer anywhere else!